# How can I exclude rows equal to a value in column a but not if equal a value in column b from the same table?

Tags: postgresql

Need to add another condition to a select statement selecting from a single table

current code:

```
SELECT program, campaign 
FROM campaign 
WHERE substring(campaign,2,1) = '_'
AND substring(campaign,1,1) != 'X'
AND substring(campaign,1,1) != 'B'
AND substring(campaign,1,1) != 'D'
AND substring(campaign,1,1) != 'R'
AND substring(campaign,1,1) != 'T'
GROUP BY program, campaign
ORDER BY program asc;
```

need to add `AND substring(campaign,1,1) != 'O'` but not if in program 'ABC'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic can be simplified to this:

```
SELECT program, campaign 
FROM campaign 
WHERE 
  substring(campaign, 2, 1) = '_' 
  AND 
  substring(campaign, 1, 1) NOT IN ('X', 'B', 'D', 'R', 'T')
  AND 
  (substring(campaign, 1, 1) <> 'O' OR program = 'ABC')
GROUP BY program, campaign 
ORDER BY program asc;
```